# Can't preview Vue app developed with Vite in a 3rd party tool iframe (but can using Vue CLI)

Tags: vue.js, proxy, port, config, vite

I am developing a Vue app that will be "iframed" into a 3rd party framework. I can develop my app locally under the localhost, but in order to preview it in the 3rd party tool, the URL should be: `https://localhost:5001/sampleapp/index.html`.

I have two versions of the same app. One was built with Vue-CLI and the 2nd one with Vite.

When I try to preview the Vite version of the app, I get a blank page.

When using Vue CLI version, I get a working app and can develop it as I would normally do, and it 'hot-reloads' in the iframe.

How do I achieve the same with Vite?

Comment: The tool is Amadeus Enterprise. They require that Network URL is: ```https://localhost:5001/```. I am able to get that with Vue CLI, but not with Vite.

Comment: @tony19   - I figured out what the issue was (and also updated the content of the question). It turned out, that for the Vite version, I actually had to run the preview mode. When I compared the frame source code, Vue-CLI was producing a regular minified JavaScript file. Vite was giving ```<script type="module" src="/sampleapp/index.html/@vite/client"</script>```. Once, in preview mode, the App was working under the iframe URL.

Comment: Glad you figured it out! Please move your answer to the answer box. Feel free to accept your own answer. This will help others that run into the same problem.

Comment: I would move it but am restricted by Stack Overflow. Not enough reputation points.

Comment: Gotcha. I've moved it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*@edytajordan's answer:*

It turned out, that for the Vite version, I actually had to run the App in the preview mode. My final vite.config.js:

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  base: '/sampleapp/index.html/',
  server: {
    port: 5001,
    https: true,
  },
  preview: {
    port: 5001,
    https: true,
  }
})
```

and then run `npm run build && npm run preview`.